# Determine if an event happened every hour for 24 straight hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Edit - I am still digesting the great responses and learning how they work, awesome knowledge!**

Using SQL Server 2016, I am trying to figure out if any users have done something at least once every hour, for 24 consecutive hours.

I have a table similar to this, in the example below, the only user who qualifies is '21482'.  They actually have more than one event an hour (which is fine) but they have done at least one thing every hour for 24 straight hours. They also have events on 8-22 but they would not qualify as they are not consecutive (i.e. there's a gap between the 8-22 events and 8-23 events).

The other user '45578', does not qualify, even though they have more than 24 events in a single day, there was not activity during every hour for 24 straight hours.  It doesn't matter if the activity spans more than a single day, that is fine.

Ideas on how to accomplish something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE AuditData
    ([UserID] varchar(20), [Event_Timestamp] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO AuditData
    ([UserID], [Event_Timestamp])
VALUES
(21482, '2021-08-22 00:15:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-22 00:25:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-22 02:05:45.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-22 04:15:15.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-22 06:25:10.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-22 08:01:05.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 00:05:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 01:05:45.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 02:15:15.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 03:25:10.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 04:01:05.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 05:55:55.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 06:50:58.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 07:30:02.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 08:10:12.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 08:14:12.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 09:18:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 10:17:32.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 11:30:21.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 11:32:21.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 12:45:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 13:01:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 14:59:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 15:44:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 16:49:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 17:50:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 18:10:30.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 19:02:45.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 20:11:50.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 21:55:15.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 22:16:55.000'),
(21482, '2021-08-23 23:58:10.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 05:05:30.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 05:05:45.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 05:15:15.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 05:25:10.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 05:41:05.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 05:55:55.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 06:50:58.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 07:30:02.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 08:10:12.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 09:18:30.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 10:17:32.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 11:30:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 11:31:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 12:32:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 13:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 13:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 13:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 14:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 14:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 14:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 14:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 15:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 15:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 15:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 15:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 15:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 16:33:21.000'),
(45578, '2021-08-23 16:33:21.000')
;
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How do you define once every hour? At least once for each hour in the day, or within/after one hour of the previous event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem.**

There are many solutions.

- One of the classic ones is to use `LAG` to check if the current row is the start of a new group, assign group IDs using a running `COUNT`, then group by this new ID

> To truncate to the beginning of the hour, we use `DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ad.Event_Timestamp), 0))`

```sql
WITH StartPoints AS (
    SELECT ad.UserID, v.Hour,
      IsStart = CASE WHEN LAG(v.Hour) OVER (PARTITION BY ad.UserID ORDER BY v.Hour)
                >= DATEADD(hour, -1, v.Hour) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END
    FROM AuditData ad
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES(DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ad.Event_Timestamp), 0))) v(Hour)
    GROUP BY ad.UserID, v.Hour
),
Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(IsStart) OVER (PARTITION BY ad.UserID ORDER BY ad.Hour ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM StartPoints ad
)
SELECT DISTINCT ad.UserID
FROM Groupings ad
GROUP BY ad.UserID, ad.GroupId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 24;
```

- Another solution is, which works here because all we are looking for is the existence of an island, is to use `LAG` with an offset of 23 to check whether that row is exactly 23 hours before current. Then we simply group by `UserID`

```sql
WITH Hours AS (
    SELECT ad.UserID, v.Hour,
        Hour24 = LAG(v.Hour, 23) OVER (PARTITION BY ad.UserID ORDER BY v.Hour)
    FROM AuditData ad
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES(DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ad.Event_Timestamp), 0))) v(Hour)
    GROUP BY ad.UserID, v.Hour
)
SELECT DISTINCT ad.UserID
FROM Hours ad
WHERE ad.Hour24 = DATEADD(hour, -23, ad.Hour);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=618a0eb8556b6d3b8cb91c68d0cf3169)

Answer (score 1):

You can summarize the data by user and hour and then use `lead()`:

```
select user_id, event_hh
from (select user_id, v.event_hh,
             lead(v.event_hh, 23) over (partition by user_id order by v.event_hh) as event_hh_23
      from AuditData ad cross apply
           (values (dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Event_Timestamp), 0)
           ) v(event_hh)
      group by user_id, v.event_hh
     ) ut
where event_hh_23 = dateadd(hour, 23, event_hh);
```

This reduces the data to one row per user and hour and then looks 23 hours ahead.  If that row is available, then there are 24 hours in a row.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of consecutive range problem, one way to tackle it is to use *window functions* to identify consecutive sequences and define each sequence as its own group, then to count the rows in each group and filter accordingly.

This requires creating a distinct consecutive sequence per hour for which `datetimefromparts` is useful.

```
with dates as (
    select distinct userid, datetimefromparts (DatePart(year,Event_Timestamp), DatePart(month,Event_Timestamp), DatePart(day,Event_Timestamp), DatePart(hour,Event_Timestamp),0,0,0) date
    from AuditData
), groups as (
    select userid, date, Row_Number() over (partition by userid order by date) rn,
        DateAdd(hour, -Row_Number() over (partition by userid order by date), date) grp
    from dates
)
select userid
from groups
group by userid,grp
having Count(*)>=24
```

[Example DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce3fcf2e0bcfe7f1bf7e99abaee8c5ea)